# Android Market Addons Structure

Tags: android, google-play, add-on

I'm building an app that will accept addons. They have the same package root, i.e. `com.mycom.appname`, whereas the addon is `com.mycom.appname.addon` and the main app is just the root.

Right now, it's structured to when the addon is downloaded, the main app intercepts the PACKAGE_ADDED intent from Android, grabs a SQLite file included in the addon and copies to the main app database.

My question is, how can I keep uploading new addons to the market without having 100 different packages? I'd like to keep everything in the `com.mycom.appname.addon package`, but it seems that I'd have to add another suffix, such as `com.mycom.appname.addon.package001` in order to keep everything packaged correctly on the market.. er, "Google Play". I checked the mutliple APK page from the Android dev site, and it doesn't seem like Google endorses this behavior.

Ultimately I'd like to have multiple add-ons supported, such as "Article Pack", "Tips Pack 10", etc on the market as separate entities.

What do you think is the best option for this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how can I keep uploading new addons to the market without having 100 different packages?

If you want 100 entries in Google Play, you need 100 different packages. Google Play requires package names to be unique.

You are welcome to handle download, installation, and updates of add-on APKs yourself, outside of Google Play, if you wish. Even in those cases, though, you would need 100 different packages for the 100 entries, if there is a chance that the user will have more than one addon installed at once. Android, at the OS level, requires package names to be unique.

If the add-on is simply a SQLite database, you are welcome to handle download, installation, and updates of add-ons that aren't APKs at all yourself (e.g., just package the database as a ZIP file). In this case, there are no package names at all to worry about.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and clarification.  Honored to have a question answered by CommonsWare ;)